# How can i save a text on an xml layout?

Tags: android, xml, textbox

Im creating a small note taking app. When i test it out and i write some text it works.But when i exit the page and come back the text is not there anymore. How can i have it that when a user exits the page/app the text will stay displayed?

Comment: You mean when you exit the app itself, or just when you go to a different activity within your application?

Comment: when i switch activity in the app

Answer (score 1):

You can use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods in your activity for this purpose. I’ve found good example how to use them here: http://android.okhelp.cz/onsaveinstancestate-onrestoreinstancestate-basic-android-example/